# persistent connections boost.asio

Tags: c++, boost-asio

I have a server and a client on boost.asio. I want the session to continue receiving new packets and processing them after receiving the first packet. If you call start recursively, the program executes the callback function indefinitely.

```cpp
class session : public std::enable_shared_from_this<session> {
public:
    session(tcp::socket&&socket) : socket(std::move(socket)){
    }
    void start() {
        async_read_until(socket, buf, "\0", 
            [self = shared_from_this()](boost::system::error_code code, size_t bytes_transferred) {
            std::string require = buffer_cast<const char*>(self->buf.data());
            std::cout << "GET: " << require << "\n";
            if (require == "Hi") {
                async_write(self->socket, buffer("Hello\0"), [](boost::system::error_code code, size_t bytes_transferred) {
                    std::cout << "SEND: Hello\n";
                    });
            }
            start();
            });
    }
private:
    tcp::socket socket;
    streambuf buf;
};
```

why is the callback function immediately called after a recursive call?

Comment: Probably the session being destructed. If you show minimal self contained code we can actually check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I must clear streambuf by way of streambuf::consume(size_t n)

Comment: Ah, consume is not clearing, it’s consuming _part_ of the buffer (the part that satisfies the match condition for read_unitil).

Answer (score 0):

There is no recursive call.

But the chained operation (async_write) fails to capture `self`. Therefore the destructor causes the operation to be cancelled.

Comment: no, i solved its. I must clear streambuf by way of streambuf::consume(size_t n)

Comment: The code as posted doesn’t match your own answer (there is no recursive call at all and you fail to capture `self` on `async_writer`, meaning session will be destructed anyways, which *does* explain the complaint that the completion handler gets invoked immediately.

Comment: yes, sorry, i corrected this code. it's just that even for a recursive call, without consume, the program will endlessly call the read message

Comment: Yes. However, you still haven’t corrected the question. It needs both corrections to make sense